# error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value with `!=` C++

Tags: c++

I have absolutely no idea why my compiler is throwing this error: 
"Error  1   error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value" with this line of code:

```
while ((input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && choice = 1) ||
      (input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && input != 4 && input != 5 && input != 6 && choice = 1) ||
      std::cin.fail()){}
```

The error appears to want `input`, which is a short, to be modifiable, but `!=` is not a modifier, it's a checker. What is going on?

Comment: Change your `choice = 1` to `choice == 1` statements.

Comment: _"There's no reason for my compiler to be throwing this error"_ Throw those assumptions out of the window if you want to learn how to solve these problems yourself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought it was a typo.

Comment: that's why in some coding standards it's recommended to write the constant first: `1 == choice`

Comment: What's with all the downvotes?!

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Meh, it's not that popular. Your compiler should be warning you, anyway.

Comment: @LarryK: The downvotes are because you did not (a) enable compiler warnings, (b) read compiler warnings, (c) search/research ... and because this question is not going to help anyone else one day. Recall that this is a Q&A repository and not a helpdesk. Cheers!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's common in the automotive industry.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Well you have a good point there: it's particularly common among the subset of programmers who write `1 == choice`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well probably it's not common in the West but it's required in my worked companies and is addressed in several coding guidelines

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: I'm very sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operator precedence dictates that your first sub-condition

```
input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && choice = 1
```

is parsed as

```
(input != 1 && input != 2 && input != 3 && choice) = 1
```

The left-hand side of `=` is not an lvalue, just like your compiler told you.

What were you trying to say by that strange combination of operators?

Comment: That was a stupid mistake. Thanks! I'm not sure if I ever would have found that.

Comment: It's a pity that there's no "language lawyer" badge...it takes a certain mentality to look past the obvious "=" versus "==" issue and explain the resulting error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your left side of (=) must be l-value, which means it must have adress in memory

Comment: Although it is true, it does not make an answer. You can improve your own answer by editing it, and add for instance, a code snipet. That would help the author of the post. For instance, write a code snippet with @shauryachats's suggestion.